# Typeahead bloodhound tokenizer - wildcarding search?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Is there an option to wildcard the search terms in Bloodhound?

For example, if a description is "Import from film_actor" then search will pick it up for film but not for actor; want it to search `*term*` and not just `term*`.

Here is my setup:

```
  var datasets = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name description'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: activeWorkspace.get('datasets')
  });
```

Comment: suggestion: you can have `obj.whitespace('name', 'description')`. I'm not quite sure about `*term*`

Comment: you are missing the point - I want to do a wildcard search of the values in the columns name and description.  you are just duplicating what I already  have.

Comment: check this https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/186

Comment: Dhiraj - that post is old, from 2 years ago, but it may be the answer, that wildcarding isn't currently implemented.